# Python treat words with comas the same as those without in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a program, that reads a .txt file and prints how many times a certain word has been used:

```
    filename = 'for_python.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    contents = file.read().split()
dict = {}
for word in contents:
    if word not in dict:
        dict[word] = 1
    else:
        dict[word] += 1


dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for i in dict:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

It works, but it treats words with commas as different words. Is there an easy and efficient way to solve this?

Comment: use spli by space like it `split(" ")`

Comment: could we have the data of `for_python.txt`, also don't name your dict `dict`, same it something like `dict1`

Comment: `from collections import Counter` and word.strip(',')

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

```
filename = 'for_python.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    contents = file.read().splitlines()
dict = {}

for sentence in contents:
    word_list = sentence.split(" ")
    for word in word_list:
        cleaned_word = " "
        for character in word: 
            if character.isalnum():
                cleaned_word += character
        if cleaned_word not in dict:
            dict[cleaned_word] = 1
        else:
            dict[cleaned_word] += 1


dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for i in dict:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```